# How to store Username for logged in user when submit a Form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to capture username of the user logged in and Store username in DB under the created Table. Here is my code.

User Class stores user details, So when a user is logged in and submits a ticket, ticket will get store in Tickets DB along with the Username who submits the Ticket. I have used User.Identity.Name in view to show the username logged in. Which does work fine, but I am unable to submit the form and data is not storing in DB.

1. User Model Class

```
public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

2. Ticket Model Class

```
public class Ticket
    {
        [Key]
        public int TicketNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Query { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Solution { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string TicketStatus { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }        
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserID")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

    }
```

3. Controllers to AddTicket GET AND POST method

```
public ActionResult AddTicket()
        {
           return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult AddTicket(Ticket model)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (Db db = new Db())
                {
                    Ticket dto = new Ticket();                                       
                    
                    dto.TicketNumber = model.TicketNumber;
                    dto.CreateDateTime = model.CreateDateTime;
                    dto.StartDateTime = model.StartDateTime;
                    dto.EndDateTime = model.EndDateTime;
                    dto.Query = model.Query;
                    dto.Solution = model.Solution;
                    dto.TicketStatus = model.TicketStatus;
                    dto.UserID = model.UserID;

                    User userDTO = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == model.UserID);
                    dto.UserName = userDTO.UserName;
                    

                    db.Tickets.Add(dto);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                TempData["SM"] = "Ticket Added succesfully";
                return RedirectToAction("AllTicket");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

4. View

```
@model CZ.Models.VM.Ticket
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddTicket";
}
<h2>AddTicket</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Ticket</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateDateTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreateDateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDateTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDateTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Query, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Query, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Query, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Solution, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Solution, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Solution, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TicketStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TicketStatus, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TicketStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @User.Identity.Name
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form is not submitting because there is no form tag present in the view.  You should also declare your model type in the view and add `Html.BeginForm` extension method which is used to generate html form tag in Asp.Net MVC Razor.

```
@model TestApp.Models.Ticket

    <h2>AddTicket</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Ticket</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateDateTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreateDateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDateTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDateTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Query, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Query, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Query, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Solution, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Solution, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Solution, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TicketStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TicketStatus, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TicketStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

Comment: I did not added here on purpose as StackOverflow was not accepting those. Even after having them added, still no success. Edited version updated. Please help

Comment: What happens when you click on submit? Did you try adding a breakpoint on this line in  your controller `if (ModelState.IsValid)`Does it get hit at all?

Comment: Yes, I did add a break point, all data comes except the username. That is what I am looking to achieve here.  TIcket created BY who? which Username? I am not getting a way to capture value from User.Identity.Name and submit to Controlled

Comment: Ok. In your controller just try to get the user name by adding the following  line in your action method  `var userName = User.Identity.Name`. And it will only have a valid username when the user is logged in  your application if not, it will be null

Comment: Thank you for your help, tried but no success. How will this line of code work?

Comment: Just add it anywhere inside the method body of `public ActionResult AddTicket(Ticket model)`

Comment: SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TicketNumber', table dbo.Tickets'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: There is nt any one to help